# Is it possible that a program sends a Segfault whenever an object tries to access one of its attributes?

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have a class with a `bool` attribute called `global`.

I have a segmentation fault happening when calling one of its methods from the outside.

Basically, I call this method. This method internally calls another method, which calls another method and so on (this is because each method does something slightly more complex).

At the end of the method calling chain there's a method which checks the attribute `global`, and does different things based on its content.

Using gdb I found out the segmentation fault error is generated at the exact line `if (global) {` in this last method. I tried moving this condition check higher in the method call chain (so that the condition is checked before continuing deeper in the method chain), but the result doesn't change (in other words, wherever it is placed, `if (global) {` always causes a segmentation fault`).

Is it possible that checking for the attribute `global` causes a segmentation fault? What could this mean? What causes this?

I am compiling usin `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g`.

Comment: Re: "What causes this?" -- an error in your code. The way to find it is to remove code until the problem goes away, then add back the last bit that you removed, and continue removing other stuff until the problem goes away again; repeat until done. Once you've gotten the code down to the smallest program you can write that compiles, runs, and shows the problem, there's a good chance that you'll have figured out what's wrong. If not, post that minimal program.

Comment: I predict that the client calls the method through an object pointer that is `NULL` or otherwise invalid. The program then crashes the first time `this` is actually used to access the object's data member.

Comment: Try adding `-fsanitize=address` to your compile & link flags, if you are seeing seg faults.  It will print out more details about *why* the seg faults occur.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) means that your program has attempted to access memory outside its address space.
This is typically caused by dereferencing uninitialized pointers or pointers to objects which lifetime has ended, reading off the end of the stack or similar.

Comment: I think it's because the lifetime of the object has ended, but is it normal that I can call a deleted object's method whitout the program noticing (or only noticing when an attribute is checked)?

Comment: Yes. The compiler doesn't stop you from engaging in Undefined Behaviour (which that is). It's *your* responsibility to just not do that.